# work and education fields of FQL table not documented

Tags: facebook

Why do the fields "work" and "education" not appear in [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) yet they seem to return exactly what i need (the ID's of the work and education fields linked to the logged in user)

```
SELECT work, education FROM user WHERE uid = me()
```

Is it recommended to not use these as they are not documented?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the fact that something in the facebook api is "undocumented" doesn't mean much. Even if there is a plan to move this data to another table, the fields will remian available (legacy support) for a while after that happens. I would use this for now, if it works, and just keep my ear to the ground in case of changes in the table structure.